# jQuery UI selectable isnt displaying the selection outline, why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

On the jQuery UI selectable demo page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#default when you select elements, you can see the selection box outline. How come this doesnt appear when I try it?

This isnt my fiddle, but it also has the same problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/jMDVm/40/

Comment: What do you mean by selection box outline? On the demo page, you select an item, and it's highlighted orange. In the fiddle, you select an item, and it's highlighted gray. What's missing?

Comment: try selecting items in the answers fiddle and try in the questions fiddle, see that there is a box outline from the point where you started clicking to the point where the mouse currently is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because it's missing the jQuery UI stylesheet, which contains the class for styling the selection helper box. Add the following to your CSS:

```
.ui-selectable-helper {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 100; 
  border: 1px dotted black; 
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#selectable").selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) {
      $('.status').text("Selected");
    },
    selecting: function(event, ui) {
      $('.status').text("Selecting");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}

#selectable {
  background: black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 16px;
}

#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: silver;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: gray;
}

#selectable div {
  background-color: #777;
}

.ui-selectable-helper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="selectable">
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Select</div>
    <div>Me</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="status"></div>
```